# Cassandra Python driver doesn't page large queries

Tags: cassandra, datastax-python-driver

It is said in the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.25/query_paging/) that cassandra-driver does automatic paging when queries are large enough (with default_fetch_size being 5000 rows) and will return `PagedResult`.

I have tested reading data from my local Cassandra which contains 9999 rows with `SimpleStatement` with my own fetch size, but it returned the ResultSet (9999 rows) instead of pages (instance of `PagedResult`). Also, I tried to change the `Session.default_fetch_size` but it didn't work as well.

Here's my code..

**My first attempt:** This is the `SimpleStatement` code i have made to change the fetch size.

```
cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect(keyspace_name)

query = "SELECT * FROM user"
statement = SimpleStatement(query, fetch_size=10)
rows = list(session.execute(statement))
print(len(rows))
```

It prints 9999 (all rows), not 10 rows as I already set the `fetch_size`.

---

**My second attempt:** I tried to change the query fetch size by changing session's default fetch size `Session.default_fetch_size`.

```
cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect(keyspace_name)
session.default_fetch_size = 10

query = "SELECT * FROM user"
rows = list(session.execute(query))
print(len(rows))
```

It also prints 9999 rows instead of 10.

---

My goal is not to limit the rows from my fetch query, such as `SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 10`. What I want is to fetch the rows page by page to avoid overload on memory.

So what actually happened?

Note: I am using Cassandra-Driver 3.25 for Python and using Python3.7

I am sorry if my additional information still doesn't make my question a good one. I never ask any questions before. So...any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: Will you please add a minimal sample code that replicates the issue but versions you're using? Here's a friendly note on how to ask good questions. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I am adding details to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test is invalid because your code is faulty.

When you `list()`, you are in fact "materialising" all the result pages. Your code is not iterating over the rows but retrieving all of the rows.

The driver automatically fetches the next page in the background until there are no more pages to fetch. It may not seem like it but each page only contains `fetch_size` rows.

Retrieving the next page happens transparently so to you it seems like the results are not getting paged at all but that automatic behaviour from the driver is working as designed. Cheers!

Comment: I see, but i want to confirm what i have understood. 
Let's say i do iterate the rows like `for row in session.execute(statement)` for my first attempt (not using `list()` anymore), it iterates through the first 10 rows. Since the total rows are 9999, it does fetch the next 10 rows from Cassandra, the process repeats until every row has successfully iterated? Am i right?

Comment: Correct, yes. The driver fetches the next page without you knowing about it, hence "transparent". It will keep fetching the next page if you keep going until there are no more pages left to fetch. Cheers!

Comment: ahh i forgot to say this, Thank you!